# Как правильно отправить запрос с параметрами из сервиса?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
Реализую *pattern A* ([из этой презентации](http://habrahabr.ru/post/240543/) ), но столкнулся с проблемой. Как вызывая сервис можно задать параметры запроса? 
По идее, вызывая сервис параметризуем *intent* и в сервисе уже через *switch* по *id*, тот или иной метод исполняем. Но как задавать параметры для запросов?

Например, мы на странице ввели в поля данные. Дальше запускаем сервис, сервис запускает в отдельном потоке метод (к серверу обращаемся, например). Вот тут и вопрос.

Обычно я бы сделал вот так:

```
private void startLoginTask() {

    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
    info.setLogin("12345");
    info.setPassword("12345");

    AuthorizationParams params = new AuthorizationParams(info);

    LoginTask task = new LoginTask(params);
    task.start(); //расширяет класс Thread. В методе run обращение к серверу
}
```

UPD: Пытаюсь реализовать нечто похожее на вышеприведённый *паттерн А*:
Активити вызывает сервис, сервис выполняет запрос к серверу, и возвращает ответ в активити (в моем случае).

Как я понял, когда мы запускаем сервис, то в интент, добавляем название метода, который хотим запустить. Сервис получает интент, и запускает нужный нам метод. Тут все хорошо.
Но вот, когда мы вводим параметры на экране, в самой активити, и потом запускаем сервис, как положить введённые в активити данные, в паараметры запроса? Отправлять через тот же интент думаю не вариант. Т.к параметров може быть очень много.

Comment: я ничего не понял. Можно раскрыть тему подробнее?

Comment: @Barmaley обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть ваш класс `AuthorizationParams` реализует интерфейс [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html),  и тогда можно будет помещать в `intent` ваш объект `AuthorizationParams` вызывая `intent.putExtra(...)`, после чего его можно будет восстанавливать в сервисе, вызывая `getParcelableExtra(...)`.
Так же можно воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, например [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice), которая реализует Pattert A.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
public class MyGeniousIntentService extends IntentService {

    //все наши параметры пихаем в класс MyParams, который реализует либо Parcelable или хотя бы Serializable
    // если параметров мало то можно просто списком

    public static void startMyAction(Context context, MyParams params) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyGeniousIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION); //наш экшн, по которому будет распозонавать тип параметра
        intent.putExtra(MY_EXTRA_PARAMS, params); //собственно сами параметры
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public MyGeniousIntentService() {
        super("MyGeniousIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (MY_ACTION.equals(action)) { //ветвимся по экшну
                final MyParams params = (MyParams )intent.getSerializableExtra(MY_EXTRA_PARAMS);
                handleMyAction(message, params);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleMyAction(MyParams params) { //рабочая лошадка
     //blah-blah
    }
}
```

Тогда в активити вызов сервиса будет выглядеть просто:

```
MyGeniousService.startMyAction(this, params);
```

Здесь приведен пример для `IntentService`, но и для обычного `Service` отличий будет немного - ну разве что самому надо будеть писать `Thread`